# Python3 and asyncio: how to implement websocket server as asyncio instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I have multiple servers, each server is instance returning by asyncio.start_server. I need my web_server to works with websockets, to have possibility getting data using my javascript client. As I can see, asyncio do not provide websockets, only tcp sockets. Maybe I missed something ? I want to implement websocket server that I can using in asyncio.gather like below:

```
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    login_server = LoginServer.create()
    world_server = WorldServer.create()
    web_server   = WebServer.create()

    loop.run_until_complete(
        asyncio.gather(
            login_server.get_instance(),
            world_server.get_instance(),
            web_server.get_instance()
        )
    )

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    loop.close()
```

I do not want to use aiohttp cause if using like in code above aiohttp just blocks another tasks. I need something that will be non-blocking and that will have access to data of another servers (login and world). Does it possible with asyncio ? Does asyncio provide something like websockets ? How to implement websocket server for using in asyncio.gather ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally I've implemented WebServer for using in another thread with asyncio. The code (WebServer code):

```
from aiohttp import web


class WebServer(BaseServer):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        super().__init__(host, port)

    @staticmethod
    async def handle_connection(self, request: web.web_request):
        ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
        await ws.prepare(request)

        async for msg in ws:
            Logger.debug('[Web Server]: {}'.format(msg))

        return ws

    @staticmethod
    def run():
        app = web.Application()
        web.run_app(app, host=Connection.WEB_SERVER_HOST.value, port=Connection.WEB_SERVER_PORT.value)
```

And how to run:

```
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()

loop.run_until_complete(
    asyncio.gather(
        login_server.get_instance(),
        world_server.get_instance(),
        loop.run_in_executor(executor, WebServer.run)
    )
)
```

Comment: Running `web.run_app` with `run_in_executor` is an anti-pattern because it (unnecessarily) runs _two_ event loops. You can use the `AppRunner` API instead, as shown in the first code snippet of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49280706/1600898).